# Count how many times I received a specific word from a HTTP response data JMeter

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server, jmeter, load-balancing

I'm testing my load balancing server, where I have two machines as server and one machine as balancer. I want to know which machine fails at the end of the test and how many times. I request the same file in both servers which just contains "machine1" and "machine2".

The load balancing algorithm used is round robin.

When I'm testing my server with JMeter I receive that body as "response data", and I have created a regular expression(Regular expression Extractor) to try to count how many times I receive "Machine2" and "Machine1" but doesn't work.

So at the end of 500 request for example, I want to know how many times Machine2 and Machine1 appears in that Responde data.

Can anyone help me?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as child of your request,

Use Regular Expression for finding, with `|` as Or condition:

```
machine1|machine2
```

Use Template `$1$` and put Match No. value as `-1`. created variable put `machine` for example

This will save number of occurrences in special variable end with `_matchNr` so you can use:

```
${machine_matchNr}
```

> If the match number is set to a negative number, then all the possible matches in the sampler data are processed. The variables are set as follows:
>
> refName_matchNr - the number of matches found; could be 0

Comment: yes, you are right but on this way just counts how many times PER request and I want in total at the end of the test.

Comment: Should I make a script to do it?

Comment: @VictorVallecillo yes, You can add JSR223 Post Processor with groovy line `vars.put("Total", (vars.get("Total").toInteger() +  vars.get("a_matchNr").toInteger()).toString())`

Comment: Thank, "it works", the problem is vars.get('machine_matchNr').toInteger() is empty, and i don't why bcs if you go to view results tree you can see how machine_matchNr get value per request. I checked and are the same name. I tried to put it as a parameter in the postprocessor but same situation.

Comment: @VictorVallecillo you can add a pre processor with `vars.put('machine_matchNr','0')`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be dynamically changing sampler name depending on response body.

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of your request
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   prev.setSampleLabel(prev.getResponseDataAsString())
   ```
3. That's it, the above script will substitute your sampler name with the response data, this way you will be able to figure out the number of samplers hitting this or that endpoint using listeners like [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report)

Demo:

[image: JMeter Demo Amend Sampler Name]

---

Don't forget to add [DNS Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps) to your test plan as in some cases JMeter can hit only one address due to caching of the DNS responses so all your load will go to a single host instead of being distributed across the cluster nodes